# Is it safe to append sensitive data to the end of https urls used in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, ssl, https

I am using an iPhone app to ping a "https" URL that looks like the following:

https://domain.com/server/unique-id/SecretInformationString

I'm assuming server logs would be vulnerable, as well as iPhone history perhaps... but would someone outside of the local network have any idea of what "SecretInformationString" is?

Comment: why don't you just send the secret stuff through POST?

Comment: good point. I think POSTing it would avoid my concerns regarding server logs and iphone logs, etc.

Comment: The URL will be visible by any system from the phone to domain.com.

Comment: @Andrew but if I POST it via a URL that has no secret information in it at all, the only thing seen by the systems in between phone/domain would be the URL that has no secret information?

Comment: @daemon Yes because the `https` means the phones http stack will establish a secure connection via tls before sending anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information added to the end of the URL will not be secure as the URL itself is sent in plain text before your request is encrypted.

If you were to make a POST request with the secret values instead the URL will still be visible to the outside world in plaintext however your post data would be encrypted.

Edit: If you are making multiple requests with the same secret data (i.e. you are using it as an authentication token) you may want to consider using a secure cookie.